# split method with multiple delimeters

Tags: java, split, delimiter

How can I use split method of java to include delimeters like `(+-/!.?:;()')` and also space as one of the delimeter. My split statement looks something like this:

```
String[] words = myDocs[i].split("[+-/!.?:;()' ]");
```

It works fine for all the delimeters except space. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: How is it not working for space? Using your split statement, `System.out.println(Arrays.toString("hello world".split("[+-/!.?:;()' ]")));` gives `[hello, world]`, which is what I'd expect to see.

Comment: Are you trapped by something which looks like a space but it is not? For example: tabs.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\\s+` in place of the space.

Comment: That's because the parameter to split is a regular expression. You can find the list of regular expression constructs there: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum